# Firefox (only) has a weird margin/padding behaviour

Tags: css, firefox, margin, padding

this page:
www.bit.ly/1b4dUqs

looks fine in every Browser (except FF (newest Version)).

FF somehow handles the margin-top/padding-top style different than others.

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: Your answer isn't very useful when all your have in your question is a bit.ly link. You'll want to reproduce some of the relevant code from your page here so the answer makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I just declare the -Element as an inline-block Element via:

```
#tenwrapper p span {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And gave them the margins.
Now everything works fine!